# Draw nicer shadow under an arrow line

Tags: c#, image, shadow

My existing code draw a fixed 'shadow' color under an arrow line. But from my view, it is urgly. I need a nicer real shadow w/ displacement (Horizontal and vertical),Opacity and blur custom arguments. How to achieve this kind of nice shadow effect in C#?

```
using (GraphicsPath _Path = new GraphicsPath())
{
    _Path.AddLine(mouseDownX, mouseDownY, mouseUpdX, mouseUpY);                           
    // Draw the shadow.
    mygraphics.TranslateTransform(3, 3); //displacement
    using (Pen _Pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(30, 0, 0, 0), hPen.Width)) 
    {
         _Pen.CustomStartCap = adjustableArrowCap_0;
         mygraphics.DrawPath(_Pen, _Path);
    }
    mygraphics.ResetTransform();
}
mygraphics.DrawLine(hPen, mouseDownX, mouseDownY, mouseUpdX, mouseUpY);
```

I attach a picture to show what is the nicer shadow means.
[image]

Comment: have you considered just drawing 2 arrows...the "shadow" one in a different color at a little offset...then the regular one on top of it?...its really just 2 arrows

Comment: The shape can be arrow,rectangle or oval. Any available shadow library in .NET to apply shadow on a GraphicsPath?

Comment: I think I have to use hard code to form a arrow line path then use a PathGradientBrush to fill the path.

Comment: This is not well supported in GDI+ - A nice shadow would need a) offset and grey b) some amount of blur but often also c) some amount of transparency. The former is simple but  blur takes some amount of tricks like drawing a few versions  with  varying alpha < 1. This implies that the shadow can't be semi-transparent. If you would need that you will have to create the shadow in a bitmap first, add transpareny and then draw it.